# JAVA Sorting a vector with .compareTo and by filling another vector

Tags: java, vector, indexoutofboundsexception, cycle

I am having some trouble sorting a vector by comparing the elements finding the  minimum and putting it in another vector that will be the sorted one using two cycles, in particular i keep having ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```java
Vector<Figure> myList = new Vector<Figure>(); //this is the vector with all the unsorted geometric shapes
Vector<Figure> listordered = new Vector<Figure>(); //the vector where i want to put them sorted
        Figure x = null;
        int indice = 0;
        System.out.println(myList.size());
        do{
        for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++) {
            x = myList.get(i);
              if(x.compareTo(MIN) <0)
                MIN=x;
                indice = myList.indexOf(MIN);
        }
        listordered.add(MIN);
        myList.removeElementAt(indice);
        System.out.println(myList.size());
        }while(myList.size()!=0);

        System.out.println(listordered);
```

My idea was to find the minimum with a cycle then add it to the sorted vector and with another cycle keep doing this untill there were no more elements in the first vector and removing each time the new minimum element found. but it doesnt work.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `Vector.sort(Comparator<? super E> c)`? (And have you considered using`ArrayList` instead of `Vector` if thread-safety is not a concern?)

Comment: A) please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly B) please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your code never resets `MIN` and `indice` between iterations of the outer `do` - `while` loop. Since the code never updates `MIN`, the second iteration unintentionally reuses the old value of `indice`, eventually causing index out of bounds exception in `removeElementAt`.

One approach to fix this is to set `indice` to zero and `MIN` to `myList.get(0)` before going into the `for` loop. In fact, you should move `indice` and `MIN` declarations inside the `do` - `whole` loop, because this is their proper scope.

Finally, you are missing curly braces around `if`'s body. This has no effect on functionality, but results in redundant processing.

**Note:** I assume that you are writing your own sort as a learning exercise. Otherwise you should use Java library functions or ordering collections.

Comment: wow yes that fixed all, thank you very much, and yes it is as an learning exercise gotta learn a lot apparently ahahah thanks again